# Why did I get “Error commiting response java.io.IOException: Broken pipe at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)” with SSL

Tags: java, sunone

I encounter this exception when i do a page redirect from http to https. And the strange thing is that i can access https in the first 10 to 20 requests. But subsequent requests that i encounter this broken pipe issue

Below is the full exception

Error commiting responsejava.io.IOException: Broken pipe at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method) at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29) at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:104) at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:75) at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:302) at com.sun.enterprise.server.ss.ASOutputStream.write(ASOutputStream.java:120) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:283) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:272) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:666) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59) at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.commit(InternalOutputBuffer.java:602) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.action(ProcessorTask.java:721) at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:188) at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:380) at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:357) at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:318) at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteResponse.finishResponse(CoyoteResponse.java:528) at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:192) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:604) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:475) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.doTask(ProcessorTask.java:426) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:281) at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:83

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved a similar issue by increasing the RAM available to the JVM, e.g:

```
java -jar <your JAR file> -Xms512m
```